# How to save a table that is generated with JS

Tags: javascript, html

My code

```
  function addveh(model, price) {

    var table = document.getElementById("tbody");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);


    cell1.innerHTML = model;
    cell2.innerHTML = "$" + price;
    cell3.innerHTML = '<button class="w3-button w3-blue">Buy</button>';

}
```

If I use the chrome console to call the function it creates the table but does not save so how would I go about saving it so that it becomes the new html page and the model and price are passed from the serverside as a string.

Edit

Comment: Saving to what? What are you running on the back-end?

Comment: define `save`...

Comment: You need AJAX for that. When you manipulate the DOM with JS, the state remains in that session only. If you want the state to persist, you can either use localStorage (stored on clientside), or use AJAX to store it on the server side.

Comment: you write the javascript in your HTML and run it on a server. save it as HTML file. it will certainly work. I am able to save it as HTML file after JS modifications :-)

Comment: If I use local storage it is only saved for me and I want to save it so that all users will be able to see it